# CSS Hover is not working as intended. Why?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to have an anchor inside a list item to be changing colors when the mouse is hovering over. It is not working properly for PORTFOLIO and CONTACT (when I hover over ABOUT, CONTACT changes color) but it not working at all for HOME and ABOUT (HOME and ABOUT do not change color at all). Why might that be?

Here is my CSS code:

```
 li a:hover{color: #E3872D;}
```

And here my HTML code:

```
 <div class="leftpart_wrap">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div class="leftpart_bottom">
            <ul id="icons">
                <!--Icons go here and their hovering attribute works perfectly-->
            </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: both `.navbar li:hover a { ... }` and `.navbar li a:hover { ... }` should work. If not, then there is some other css that interferes with this css.

Comment: Can not reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/ognbd7s2/. You probably have some other element positioned over the top of the links.

Comment: What you've shown us would not result in what you describe. We can't help unless we can see everything that's acting on your page. Have you used your document inspector to see what CSS is affecting your element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a few things. Your code is correct but probably has some overwriting style in your CSS. Try using more specific CSS to see if it resolves:

```
.navbar li a:hover{color: #E3872D;}
```